# Next.js Dynamic Routing Failure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So im trying to do a Dynamic routing for a recipe app and its saying page not found and i have no clue why i am very new to typescript not react though.

```
// pages/recipes/[recipeId].tsx
import React from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Recipe from '../../components/recipe';// Make sure the import path matches your actual component path.

export function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ recipeId: 'spaghettiCarbonara' }, { recipeId: 'lasagna' }, { recipeId: 'pizza' }];
}

export default function RecipePage({ params }: { params: { recipeId: string } }) {
  const {recipeId} = params

  if (!recipeId) {
    console.log("hello")
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  const recipeFileName = `${recipeId}.json`;
  window.alert(recipeFileName)

  // Load recipe data from JSON file
  //const recipeData = require(`../data/recipes/${recipeFileName}`);
  const recipeData = {
    "title": "Spaghetti Carbonara",
    "ingredients": ["Spaghetti", "Eggs", "Pancetta", "Parmesan Cheese"],
    "methods": ["Boil spaghetti", "Cook pancetta", "Mix eggs and cheese", "Combine all ingredients"]
  }
  console.log(recipeData)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <Recipe recipe={recipeData} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the one i want and the file path is at the top

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Home() {

  const recipes = [
    { id: 'spaghettiCarbonara', title: 'Spaghetti Carbonara' },
    { id: 'chanaMasala', title: 'Chana Masala' },
    // Add more recipe objects here...
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Recipe App</h1>
      <ul>
        {recipes.map((recipe) => (
          <li key={recipe.id}>
            <Link href={`/recipes/${recipe.id}`}>
              {recipe.title}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the home page where it actually shows recipes you can get up? is there something im not doing. Help is very much apprieciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing 2 things.

1. app router
2. pages router

pages router is the old way to structure pages and code patterns in NextJS. it is still usable and supported by NextJS but the app router is recommended. Anyway, you are putting the code of app router's approach into pages directory approach.

The solution is to just change the paths like this:

1. `/pages/_document.tsx` => `/app/layout.tsx` (make it simple function component with native jsx tags e.g. <html>, <body>)
2. `/pages/index.tsx` => `/app/page.tsx`
3. `/pages/recipes/[recipeId].tsx` => `/app/recipes/[recipeId]/page.tsx`

you can learn more in nextjs documentation: 
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes

Comment: thanks for the help i ended up doing it before this reply by just changing the folder to [recipe] and the page.tsx inside it but the recipe is just in the app folder

Comment: @willtherandomerprice I could not understand. you still have problem?